# YouTube Data API v3 - parameter "publishedAfter" didn't work

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm using ***youtube.activities.list*** which belongs YouTube Data API v3 to develop a feature,
but I meet a problem about this API.
When I add the parameter "***publishedAfter***" to query the data,
I notice that parameter doesn't work,
it means the query result is not only the data which published after a specified time.
I've checked the format of parameter is ISO8601 (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ),
and make the parameter correct.
Please give me any idea about this problem as you can.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work with this parameter. Did you check that the format you used was correct? There are at least two ways of depicting ISO 8601 format:
1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00 or 1994-11-05T13:15:30Z
If you use the first one, the API will not give the right result, as mentioned in the documentation, they need the format to be same as 1994-11-05T13:15:30Z.
This link is from the API documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the two parameters publishedAfter and publishedBefore in a query.
Try it:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&maxResults=5&publishedBefore=2016-06-03T09%3A00%3A00Z&publishedAfter=2016-06-03T00%3A00%3A00Z&q=youtube&key={YOUR-API-KEY}